# How do I load jquery snippets after full load of html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload

Is there any way to load these snippets after full load of html?
I'd be very happy if loading the snippets after the js file (set to ASYNC load) or even set a timer.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){var modals = ['#bookings', '#studios', '#mygallery', '#social', '#reviews', '#articles', '#contactme', '#credits', '#pagemap', '#tsandcs', '#events'];if (window.location.hash && ~modals.indexOf(window.location.hash)) {$(window.location.hash).modal();}})</script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#myModal11").modal('show');});</script>
<script>$(".modal:not(.noclose) a").click(function(){$(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");});</script>
```

Comment: the first 2 load after page has loaded the last need a document ready statement as te above do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Behaviour
Hope this helps !

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

// My Html Here

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var modals = ['#bookings', '#studios', '#mygallery', '#social', '#reviews', '#articles', '#contactme', '#credits', '#pagemap', '#tsandcs', '#events'];
    if (window.location.hash && ~modals.indexOf(window.location.hash)) {
        $(window.location.hash).modal();
    }

$("#myModal11").modal('show');

$(".modal:not(.noclose) a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
    });
});

</script>
</body>
```

//  And Remove this click function and use .on instead of it for single handler

```
$(".modal:not(.noclose)").on("click","a",function(){
    $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing this but it triggers a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You are putting them in a document on ready function,

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#myModal11").modal('show');});
```

Just put the last one in that same on ready function and you're good to go

Although you could just put in them in one of those functions too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // put all code here...
});
```